# Form Only Posting In 1 Column

Tags: php, forms

Can someone explain or show me why my form is only posting in 1 column when it should be posting in 2 columns for example.

Here is my form

```
<form action="{$baseurl}/redirect" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="details_change">
    <textarea name="about_me" cols="53" rows="5" class="submit_form_textfield">{$profile_user.about_me}</textarea>
    <input type="text" name="profile_message" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="user_details" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit_form_button" value="Update Details" id="details_change">
</form>
```

And here is my PHP

```
if (isset($action) && $action=='user_details' && isset($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'])) {
    $user = new User();
    if (isset($_POST['about_me']) && isset($_POST['about_me'])) {
        $_POST['$about_me'] = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/i","",$_POST['about_me']);
    } else {
        $about_me = '';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['profile_message']) && isset($_POST['profile_message'])) {
        $_POST['$profile_message'] = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/i","",$_POST['profile_message']);
    } else {
        $profile_message = '';
    }

    $user->update($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'],array("about_me" => $about_me,"profile_message" => $profile_message));   
}
```

And I have columns in my user table called `about_me` and `profile_message`

And what happens is it will only post `about_me` and not `profile_message` any reason why?

Comment: Why your `submit` button and `form` has the same `id` defined ?

Comment: Why asking the same condition two times in the if's? Are you sure you want to assign $_POST['$about_me'] and not $_POST['about_me']? What are the values of the both $_POST[] variables, did you print that out to see what they contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$_POST['user_details']` and `$_POST['profile_message']`

In HTML:

```
<form action="{$baseurl}/redirect" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="details_change">
    <textarea name="about_me" cols="53" rows="5" class="submit_form_textfield">{$profile_user.about_me}</textarea>
    <input type="text" name="profile_message" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user_details" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit_form_button" value="Update Details" name="action" >
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'])) {
    $user = new User();

    if (isset($_POST['profile_message'])) {
        $profile_message = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/i","",$_POST['profile_message']);
    } else {
        $profile_message = '';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['user_details']) && isset($_POST['user_details'])) {
        $user_details = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/i","",$_POST['user_details']);
    } else {
        $user_details = '';
    }

    $about_me = $_POST['about_me'];

    $user->update($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'],array("about_me" => $about_me,"profile_message" => $profile_message));   
}
```

Comment: Where? Maybe he needs to change $action to $_POST['action'] but not $_POST['profile_message']. The textfield is named profile_message so this should work.

Comment: @Marcel Balzer <input type="hidden" name="action" value="user_details" /> ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, but you changed $action to $_POST['action'], too ;) And not $_POST['profile_message'] to $_POST['action']. You've edited your post correctly ;)